# How to increment var with a delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to animate an element while the user overs a link

```
var i = 0;

function next(){
    while (i>-10) {
        i--;
        $('#conteudo').animate({left:"'"+i+"px'"},'slow');
    };
}

$('#next').hover(function(){
    next();
});
```

but its instantly incrementing the value -10.. im trying to do something like this: -1..-2..-3..-4.. until it get to -10. Can I control the delay before it increments?

what im doing wrong?

here's the link for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KwhSg/

Comment: Can we see a demo of something like you're trying to do - where it has been done on another site, perhaps? Just I think people might be getting the wrong idea here - from your code, this will only ever run once. So if you hover, unhover, and hover again, the code inside `next()` will only execute the first time as, as you rightly say, `i` decrements to -10 pretty much instantly. By my reckoning, you want this to happen every time the user hovers over `#next`, am I right?

Comment: PS If you want it to happen every time the user hovers over `#next`, set `i = 0` inside the `hover` function. I'm not sure if this executes only on mouse enter or constantly whilst hovered over it, mind.

Comment: 1min ,ill post it on jsfiddle

Comment: i posted the link on the question

Comment: in fact it'll scroll #conteudo to -5000px.. i just posted -10 only to try to understand

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? While the mouse is over the link, animate the target element to the left until the mouse leaves the link?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/fdjxZ/3/ - I also tried to make it so that it starts again at one end instead of just disappearing completely when you get to the end. It works ok if you're Superman, although I suspect even he might have difficulty reading it at that speed. Just adjust the step to however much you want it to move every 30 milliseconds.

Comment: I also adjusted the CSS mind, just so it doesn't use horrible margins, clears and so on. It uses `text-align` for the menu instead.

Comment: yes man! you got the idea! but how can i stop if it reaches -5000px?

Comment: You'd want to stop it when it reaches `-($("#conteudo").width())` (not sure if this, exactly, will work in jQuery - may need to do `-1 * ...` - but in theory this should account for any changes to the width of `#conteudo` in the future. If this is the solution you're looking for, let me know and I'll post it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: yes, when it reaches the content width it'll stop. i tried do what u wrote here but its not working

Comment: Can you post what you have as a JS fiddle?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you misunderstood what [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) does. Try replacing the whole thing by this:

```
$('#next').hover(function(){
    $('#conteudo').animate({left:'-=10'},'slow');
});
```

[`Animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) already takes care of the animation, delays, the works.

Comment: ah, BTW you've one extra `{` in `animate`

Comment: its not working very well. when i hover the link it animates to -10px. i want while user hovers the link it keep incrementing and stops if mouseout

Comment: then the use should be very quick with the mouse. `while (i>-10);` is not going to take much time before it stops ;)

Comment: i think i did it wrong, its not working at all :(. i posted the jsfiddle link on the question

Comment: Check my answer, modified your jsfiddle code to what you want I think

Answer (score 2):

Like another answerer pointed out, `animate` is designed to take care of this for you. But for the sake of learning, here's how to do what you're trying to do:

```
var i = 0;
function next(){
    $('#conteudo').css({left:"'"+i+"px'"});
    // use setTimeout to pause for 30 milliseconds and let the view update
    if (i-- > -10) setTimeout(next, 30);
}

$('#next').hover(function(){
    next();
});
```

You need to use `setTimeout` instead of a while loop. It pauses (30 milliseconds in this case) between iterations so that the view can update.

In your original attempt, as long as the while loop is executing, it has total control of the process, so the view can't update until the loop is finished. Once the loop is finished, it's already done decrementing `i`, so you don't get any animation.

Comment: "As long as the while loop is executing..." - what while loop are you referring to? By my reckoning the view could be updated within the 30 milliseconds outside of this code. Another function could quite happily set `left` back to 0 within the 30 milliseconds.

Comment: The while loop in his question—his first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You could have set a boolean variable that can be set on your "hover over" event to true, and false on your "hover out" event, so your while loop would be like so

```
function next(){
    while (i>-10 && !notHovered) {
        i--;
        $('#conteudo').animate({left:"'"+i+"px'"},'slow');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the setTimeout function

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

just use that to increment your animation values at a given interval

Since this still isn't resolved, here's a solution. You can change the timeout / animation speed as necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/649az/

```
var i =10;
function next(){        
     $('#conteudo').animate({left:"-=10"},'slow');
}


$('#next').hover(function(){

    while (i>0){
        i--;
       setTimeout(next(),1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: this `setTimeout` will call `undefined` because `next()` is immediately called and returns `undefined`. even if you would change it to `setTimeout(next,1000);` it would not make much sense because then after 1000 millisecs `next`  will be called 10 times.

Comment: jquery animations are queued, thats why it seems to work, but your example would run exactly the same way when you remove the `setTimeout(next(),1000);`  and just write `next();` there. the `setTimeout` hat no effect in your code. place a `console.log` in the `next` function and you will see it.